# Add a category for all selected emails using Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2016, office-2016

I'm trying to add a category to every email selected in Outlook using VBA.

The problem is that the code below adds the category only to the **first** email.

I'm using Outlook 2016.

```
Public Sub MarkSelectedAsGreenCategory()
    Dim olItem As MailItem
    
    Dim newCategory As String
    newCategory = "Green category"
    
    Dim i As Integer
    
    For i = 1 To Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count
        Set olItem = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(i)
        AddCategory olItem, newCategory
        Set olItem = Nothing
    Next
      
End Sub

Private Sub AddCategory(mailItem As mailItem, newCategory As String)
    Dim categories() As String
    Dim listSep As String

    ' Get the current list separator from Windows regional settings
    listSep = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\sList")

    ' Break the list up into an array
    categories = Split(mailItem.categories, listSep)

    ' Search the array for the new category, and if it is missing, then add it
    If UBound(Filter(categories, newCategory)) = -1 Then
        ReDim Preserve categories(UBound(categories) + 1)
        categories(UBound(categories)) = newCategory
        mailItem.categories = Join(categories, listSep)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update to a category on `ActiveInspector.CurrentItem` would generate a prompt to save.

For a selection:

`olItem.Save` or `mailItem.Save` at your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corresponding code for removing a category:

```
Public Sub RemoveCategory(mailItem As mailItem, oldCategory As String)
    Dim categories() As String
    Dim listSep As String

    ' Get the current list separator from Windows regional settings
    listSep = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\sList")

    ' Break the list up into an array
    categories = Split(mailItem.categories, listSep)

    ' Search the array for the new category, and if it is present, then remove it
    If UBound(Filter(categories, oldCategory, True, vbTextCompare)) <> -1 Then
        categories = Filter(categories, oldCategory, False, vbTextCompare)
        mailItem.categories = Join(categories, listSep)
    End If
End Sub
```